# how update telegram source in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, telegram

i'm working on telegram source code to make customization and make my own version of telegram. telegram  version that I'm use is  3.1 .
how can i use git to update my source code with last version of telegram (version 4.6)?

Comment: Can you share your research so far to approach this, what steps you have undertaken so far and how your current setup is?

Comment: i used git for pull  all change from new source and its cause many conflict

Comment: Then you have to resolve the conflicts